# how do I select .class-a:nth-child only when it also has class .class-b

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have a grid of images. Within this grid I have albums. The albums are displayed as a single image (images-album-cover) until they are expanded, after which the entire album is displayed among the rest of the images (images-album-images).

Both images-album-cover and images-album-image have the class images-image-col. images-image-col is also the class of the rest of the non-album images.

I've added a border (with a div, not an actual border) to the bottom of each album image to indicate which images are part of an album.

I need to be able to do a few things:

select each images-album-cover OR images-album-image that is on the left side of the grid.

select each images-album-cover OR images-album-image that is on the right side of the grid.

select each images-album-image that is the last image in an album.

So far I have been able to select the left images and right images when the grid has only non-album images, but I'm at a loss of how to handle this with the albums which is when I actually need it. Not only am I unable to select the nth-child only when it matches a certain class, but when the grid has any albums in it at all nth-child stops working as it was with no albums even though I'm trying to target all images (images-image-col)

Heres a [fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaEXer) of it working (on large screens) without albums.

As soon as I started with the albums, I haven't even been able to select just the first images-album-cover, which i tried with this:

```
&:nth-child(2n+1) {
  .images-album-cover {
    outline: 1px dashed mediumvioletred;
  }
}
```

and that doesn't seem to do anything

here is the HTML for the album

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-cover open">
  <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
    <img>
    <div class="album-label">
      <figcaption>asdfasf <span>(5)</span></figcaption>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="images-album-cover-bar"></div>
</div>
<span id="gallery-detail-22">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
  </div>
</span>
```

I'm open to a JS solution if you guys think that would be better but in any case i'd still like to know if this is possible.

Comment: There is no CSS that can select _each images-album-cover OR images-album-image that is on the left side of the grid_. Also, Mostafa's answer solve the title question _how do I select .class-a:nth-child only when it also has class .class-b_.... If you want to attract more experienced users to post an answer, you need to make this question more clear (maybe with some drawing that show the wanted output) and break multiple requirements into questions of their own.

Comment: Btw, a _span_ (`<span id="gallery-detail-22">`) is not valid as a wrapper around block level element

Comment: @LGSon I know that i can't have css to do "or" with nth child, my plan was to just to target them separately with the same css.

If Mostafa's code is correct, and I'm not saying its not, how come its not working for images-album-cover?

Comment: In these samples I added the `images-album-cover` class (also added background-color to make it is easy to see which works), and I added Mostafa's rule ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eErWOO ... and as you can see it works just fine. ... Now, when you add the _gallery-detail_ wrapper, it can't be every 2nd `2n+1`, it has to be every 4th `4n+1` ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvRmpY ... so Mostafa's concept works, simply need to adjust the steps

Comment: @LGSon ah ok I see, yea you're right he did answer my question. Unfortunately i just realized the problem that the gallery detail imposes on the end goal and that what I'm trying to do might not be possible with CSS alone.

If you're down to take a look, I forked the pen and made some minor changes so that the issue is more clear. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzKRJm

Comment: Had a look. Do you mean to target every 2nd child in `<div class="images-album-contents">`? .... If not, can you make a drawing showing the wanted output

Comment: i need to be able to target the first and last columns in the a grid without rows and a with some of the items contained within a wrapper div.

Heres a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/mo9ZU

Comment: No problem to recreate the image you show, but still don't understand how you mean with what you wrote. As I see it, you have first a `images-image-col`, then a `images-image-col images-album-cover`, and then a `images-album-contents` (which holds a bunch of `images-album-image`) ... are these considered as a _group_ which gets repeated over and over?

Comment: yes, but just to be clear, i don't want to target images-album-contents, I want to target the images-image-col within them, and without starting the count over.

Comment: Ahh... well that is not possible without a script, and the reason is, when you use `nth-child`, all the items needs to be siblings sharing the **same** parent, which won't be the case here.

Comment: Yea thats what i was beginning to think, to be completely honest i completely forgot about the gallery-detail container when i first posted this.

Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Btw, if _first and last columns_ is meant for the items inside `images-album-contents`, you can use `first-child` and `last-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:nth-child(2n+1).images-album-cover {
    outline: 1px dashed mediumvioletred;
}
```

Comment: specifically its not being applied to the album cover

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use something like:

```
&:nth-child(2n+1) {
    &.images-album-cover {
        outline: 1px dashed mediumvioletred;
    }
}
```

BTW, per your code seems that you're using SASS, I'm answering taking that for granted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the wrapper

```
<span id="gallery-detail-22"></span>
```

which is messing up the nth-child numbering. I suggest you take that out. If you need to identify which album images are associated with an album cover so that you can show/hide them, perhaps add a data attribute to each one, such as

```
data-album="gallery-detail-22"
```

so your album html would be

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-cover open">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
        <img>
        <div class="album-label">
          <figcaption>asdfasf <span>(5)</span></figcaption>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-cover-bar"></div>
</div>    
<div data-album="gallery-detail-22" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
</div>
<div data-album="gallery-detail-22" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
</div>
<div data-album="gallery-detail-22" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
</div>
<div data-album="gallery-detail-22" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
</div>
<div data-album="gallery-detail-22" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 images-image-col images-album-image">
    <a class="thumbnail image images-image-thumbnail">
      <img>
    </a>
    <div class="images-album-image-bar"></div>
</div>
```

All divs with the class images-image-col would be siblings of each other, so .images-image-col:nth-child(2n+1) will work.